# Are there any linux terminals which can handle all key combinations?

Tags: terminal, tty, terminal-emulator, konsole

I like to use emacs in terminal mode (`-nw`), but it seems most (all?) terminals can't handle some key combinations - for example, `C-<RET>` or `C-M-%`. I know this is because most terminals emulate a VT-100, which didn't have these combinations. Are there any linux terminals (preferably KDE) which can handle these key combinations, or is this a fundamental limitation of all terminals?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you press a key or key combination in a terminal, it is transmitted to the application running in the terminal as a sequence of one or more characters. For example, when you press <kbd>a</kbd>, the application receives `a`. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the application receives the character `CR` (a.k.a. `^M` (pronounced “control-emm”), a.k.a. character number 13, a.k.a. `\r` or `\015`). Key combinations involving <kbd>Alt</kbd> are typically transmitted as the character `ESC` (a.ka. `^[` a.k.a. `\e` or `\033`) followed by the sequence for the key or key combination without <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Function keys and other key combinations are transmitted as escape sequences beginning with `\e[` or `\eO`.

The escapes sequences are not fully standardized, and terminals typically ignore certain attributes for certain keys. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> is often transmitted exactly like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> by default.

You can see what your terminal sends for a key combination by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by that key combination in a shell prompt, or `C-q` or `C-h c` followed by the key combination in Emacs.

With some terminal emulators, you can configure the escape sequences for each key. On Xterm, this is done through [X resources](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man7/X.7.html#sect13). Most setups read resources from `~/.Xresources` when X starts, and you can load the file manually with `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`.

```
Term.VT100.translations:       #override \n\
    Ctrl ~Shift ~Meta <key>Return: string("\033[73;5~") \n\
    Ctrl Shift ~Meta <key>percent: string("\033[37;6~")
```

A common convention uses escape sequences of the form `ESC [ number1 ; number2 ~` for function keys with modifiers. `number1` indicates the function key (`15` to `24` for <kbd>F5</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> — for historical reasons, F1 through <kbd>F4</kbd> have different escape sequences) and `number2` indicates the modifier (`2` for <kbd>Shift</kbd>, `3` for <kbd>Meta</kbd>, `5` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, `7` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>, and add 1 for <kbd>Shift</kbd> with at least one of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd>).

Emacs translates escape sequences into its internal key representation through [`input-decode-map` or `local-function-key-map`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html) (or `function-key-map` before Emacs 23).

```
(define-key local-function-key-map "\033[73;5~" [(control return)])
(define-key local-function-key-map "\033[37;6~" [(control ?L)])
```

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, I need to first define an escape sequence in my terminal which corresponds to some key combination. Then, in emacs, I need to map the escape sequence back to the key combination.
Can the escape sequence be arbitrary, as long as it doesn't conflict with those defined in `infocmp $TERM`?

Comment: @Yossarian Yes. In addition to not conflicting, the escape sequences need to be unambiguous, i.e. no escape sequences should be a prefix of another one. This means in practice that the first character has to be `ESC` (unless you want to try some character ≥128, but that will restrict the possible input encodings) and the second character has to be something for which you want no `ESC foo` binding.

Comment: I've just got round to trying what you suggested. Should `local-set-key` actually be `define-key`? The former gives an error (wrong number of arguments), while the latter works, at least for <kbd>C-Enter</kbd>. It seems konsole still has trouble sending <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>.

Comment: @Yossarian Indeed, it should be `define-key`. I don't know if Konsole's escape keys can be configured, xterm is probably more customizable than any alternative.

Comment: Note that [Thomas Dickey's xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) is under active development. With the `XTerm*modifyOtherKeys: 2` resource it will generate unique sequences even for `C-M-` combinations, but with that setting you will need to provide a lot of custom mappings (`XTerm*modifyOtherKeys: 1` is less capable but far more functional out of the box). For an example (albeit one which didn't work for me) see the `xterm-extras.el` library and the associated `.Xresources` and `.inputrc` files in the [easymacs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easymacs/) download.

Comment: Cross-referencing with http://stackoverflow.com/a/17267661/324105

Comment: +1. but references to the provided facts would be quite relevant

Comment: In my terminal, backspace and ctrl+backspace both give `^?`. Is there any possible way to distinguish between backspace and ctrl+backspace?

Comment: @trusktr Maybe. It depends on your terminal emulator. You need to configure your terminal emulator to send different escape sequences.

Comment: Seems it's not possible with vte terminals yet (Gnome Terminal, Mate Terminal, Guake, etc) as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

For a limited but significant set of keys, assuming KDE's konsole, one may do the following to have working, complex keybindings in emacs -nw:

I will use my implementation of getting `S-<RET>` to work as an example:

1. Open a new konsole, go to settings -> current profile -> keyboard -> edit
2. Hit Add and make a new entry for `Return+Shift` and give it a useful key sequence (I chose `\E[27;3` which I think is the key sequence sent by X when I was poking around with xev, but that may be wrong -- the important thing to do is make sure that it has a proper escape and doesn't conflict with anything else).
3. Play with it in the little test area at the bottom to make sure it is working.
4. Restart konsole.
5. Start up `emacs -nw` and in the scratch buffer evaluate:

   `(read-key-sequence-vector "Type your new key:")`

   then type your new key combination.

   - If you are unfamiliar with this, write the line out, leave the cursor at the end of the line, and hit C-x C-e to get emacs to run that line, it should say to you whatever you put in the quotes and wait for you to type something.
6. It should spit out a key sequence which you may bind.
   (It returned `[27 91 50 55 59 51]` to me as opposed to the boring old `[13]` before I messed with the konsole keybinding.)
7. Add to your emacs configuration:

   ```
   (define-key function-key-map [27 91 50 55 59 51] [(shift return)])
   ```
8. I tested it with `emacs -nw` in a screen session using:

   ```
   (define-key ess-mode-map [(shift return)] #'ess-eval-line-and-step)
   (define-key sh-mode-map [(shift return)]  #'send-line-to-shell)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are some efforts of extending the VT protocol in a way to allow lossless keyboard input (among other features, such as graphics).

One example is notty: https://github.com/withoutboats/notty

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it is a fundamental limitation of all terminals.

The slightly longer answer is that even if someone created a terminal that does what you want, Emacs itself would require major changes to work with this hypothetical terminal.

Comment: That's a good point about emacs, that didn't even occur to me. I guess I'll start using the gui instead.

Comment: That's what I do.