# Does ctrl-; (semicolon) not do anything on Linux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have been trying to make a keyboard binding in `tmux`'s root key-table (no prefix) for `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`;`, but haven't been able to get it to work.

I then realised that in bash `Ctrl`-`v`, `Ctrl`-`;` returns only `;`, so typing `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`;` is the same as typing `Alt`-`;`.

So is it not possible to use `Ctrl`-`;` at all in Linux? Is there anything I could do to make it work?

I am using a UK keyboard if that is making any difference here.

Comment: You can configure your terminal emulator to send a special sequence upon pressing `Ctrl-;`. If your terminal supports it (xterm and mlterm do support it).  Your keyboard layout does not make any difference.

Comment: This answers your question: [Why can't Emacs running in a terminal distinguish Ctrl+; from ";"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161719/why-cant-emacs-running-in-a-terminal-distinguish-ctrl-from)

Comment: Expanding on Cocaine Mitch's comment, you can configure some terminal emulators to send a different thing when `;`, `ctrl+;`, `ctrl+alt+;`, ..., well, different keys + mods are pressed. Luckily we are not stuck in 1980. If you are interested, see my Q&A: [Mapping otherwise conflicting or unmappable keys in terminal Vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631241/mapping-otherwise-conflicting-or-unmappable-keys-in-terminal-vim) (it's not really Vim specific, I must change that title).

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks. I use Alacritty. It's easy enough to bind keys in the config. but I just don't know what I am supposed to bind it to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping otherwise conflicting or unmappable keys in terminal Vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631241/mapping-otherwise-conflicting-or-unmappable-keys-in-terminal-vim)

Comment: @AdminBee That is the same link the Quasimodo gave immediately above and my response still stands.

Comment: @paradroid That is the standard auto-generated comment when a question is a suspected duplicate. It seems I misunderstood your response to Quasimodos suggestion.

Comment: @Quasímodo I have been trying to look into tmux user-keys from your earlier comment that you deleted, but confused about why you mentioned `"\e[88;5u"`, as isn't that `ctrl+shift+x`? How would I find the code for `ctrl-alt-;`?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was wrong but it wasn't (I made a mistake when putting it in .tmux.conf). Anyway, in the linked question you find how to find the code for `ctrl-alt-;` — not that it matters, because, if you bind `ctrl-alt-;` to `\e[88;5u` the terminal emulator will respect your order none the wiser. Should you need help, feel free call me to a chat room.